# Как программно нажать на обьект или как установить "Фокус" на EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

У меня есть объект EditText, я его сделал невидимым на экране, а при нажатии на пункт меню он появляется на экране, но как хотелось бы того на него фокус не устанавливает. Под фокусом я имею ввиду, что появляется клавиатура для ввода текста в этот EditText. Т.е. мне надо сделать программно то, что аналогично, если человек сам нажмёт на объект EditText.

Answer (score 5):

Надо объявить как focusable

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Потом вызвать `EditText.requestFocus()`

Comment: Фокус на EditText ставится и начинает моргать палка "|", но клавиатура не выводится.

Comment: Нашёл решение. По мимо предложенного в ответе, необходимо использовать ещё такой код: 

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void showInputMethod() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) (ваша Activity).getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm != null) {
        imm.showSoftInput((ваш EditText), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вообще никак не подействовало. EditText не был выделен и клавиатура не появилась

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий вариант

```
et_pass.post(new Runnable(){
@Overridе
    public void run()
{
    et_pass.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(et_pass, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
});
```